# Apollo Client throwing NPE when ApolloQueryCall.enqueue is called

Tags: apollo-client, graphql-java

I am learning GraphQL Client to Server communication using JAVA. I am using Apollo-Client now. facing issue on executing query throug java client.

My GraphQL Schema:

```
type Query {
  bookById(id: ID): Book
}

type Book {
  id: ID
  name: String
  pageCount: Int
  author: Author
}

type Author {
  id: ID
  firstName: String
  lastName: String
}
```

My Query Schema

```
query BookById($id: ID!) {
    bookById(id: $id) {
        name
    }
}
```

I have generated Java Client code from Apollo Gradle Plugin.

Below is my client code:

```
public class Client {
    private static final String BASE_URL = "https://localhost:8080/graphql";

    private ApolloClient apolloClient;
    private AtomicInteger result;

    @Test
    public void connectServer() throws InterruptedException {
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .build();
        apolloClient = ApolloClient.builder()
                .serverUrl(BASE_URL)
                .okHttpClient(okHttpClient)
                .build();

        BookByIdQuery bookByIdQuery = new BookByIdQuery("book-1");

        ApolloQueryCall<BookByIdQuery.Data> query = apolloClient
                .query(bookByIdQuery);

        System.out.println(bookByIdQuery.queryDocument());

        query.enqueue(new CallBackImpl());

        Thread.currentThread().join();
    }


    private class CallBackImpl extends ApolloCall.Callback<BookByIdQuery.Data> {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(@Nonnull Response<BookByIdQuery.Data> response) {
            log.info(response.data().bookById().name());

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@Nonnull ApolloException e) {
            log.info("Fail:" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

When I ran this client program it is throwing:

```
Exception in thread "OkHttp Dispatcher" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Client$CallBackImpl.onFailure(Client.java:61)
at com.apollographql.apollo.ApolloCall$Callback.onNetworkError(ApolloCall.java:115)
at com.apollographql.apollo.internal.RealApolloCall$1.onFailure(RealApolloCall.java:238)
at com.apollographql.apollo.internal.interceptor.ApolloCacheInterceptor$1$1.onFailure(ApolloCacheInterceptor.java:91)
at com.apollographql.apollo.internal.interceptor.ApolloParseInterceptor$1.onFailure(ApolloParseInterceptor.java:63)
at com.apollographql.apollo.internal.interceptor.ApolloServerInterceptor$1$1.onFailure(ApolloServerInterceptor.java:89)
at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:148)
at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Server Side Error:

```
ava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name. HTTP method names must be tokens
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:414) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:294) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_121]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_121]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_121]
```

From insomnia client the same call is working fine on URL: https://localhost:8080/graphql:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replaced https to http in BASE_URL.
Server was not able to understand https request.